# How to free exact agent with certain parameter from Wait Block in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am working on model, where I need to 1 agent from wait block. So please refer to the first image,

[image]

I have the following parameters of the population agents.

Now, refer to the second image,

[image]

Now, based on the parameter duedate, I am generating the dynamic event to release agents from the wait block.

But my issue is, it just randomly releases one agent from the wait block using the code

```
wait.free(wait.get(0))
```

But my requirement is that, it should release the agent with agent ID 1 (Refer to image 3).

[image]

And if that agent is not available, i want to wait and release it as soon as it is available in the wait block.

Comment: the dynamic event can take a parameter, which should be the agent that you want to free

Comment: for(int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
main.create_PickOrder(duedate, agentID);
}


will this work?

Comment: that would work if you can find the agent using the agentID

Comment: wait.free(findFirst(wait,w->w.agentID==agentID)) something like that